# Why is U2F login a two-step protocol?

Tags: fido-u2f

In theory, logging-in with a registered token could be accomplished in a single step...

1. server sends challenge with the login form
2. user responds with username, password and signed challenge.

However the FIDO protocol adds an additional step...

1. user submits username/password
2. server sends challenge to the user
3. client submits signed challenge

What is the security rationale for the additional step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Short answer**

Because there are several keys on the FIDO U2F device and anonymity/privacy is assured between different services.

- **Details**

Each time a user associates (enrollment/registration step) a FIDO U2F device (USB Token/Security Key or NFC Card or BLE device soon) with his online service account, a new key pair is created for this identity with a reference id (Key Handle), public key and key handle are sent and stored on server side. Key pairs (identities) are not shared between different online services (e.g. the key pair created for a Gmail account won't be used for a Facebook account).

Once a key pair is created, when the user sends his username and password (the authentication step), server checks which key handle(s) is/are already associated with this account and key handle(s) is/are sent with server challenge to the client (browser then FIDO U2F device) in order to ask for the right private key to be used for the signature.

Side Note: One FIDO U2F device can be associated with several online services accounts. One service account can be associated with several FIDO U2F devices.

- **More details**

Here is a quick FIDO U2F CHEAT SHEET I made to better understand registration and authentication steps because it is easy to get lost inside official FIDO U2F specification:
http://www.neowave.fr/pdfs/FIDO-U2F-CHEAT-SHEET.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Frederic, and thanks for the cheatsheet. I still don't understand, though. If I visit the Facebook login page, all I need to know is the appId and then I can select the appropriate key to sign a challenge embedded within the page, no? Then the server verifies the signature using the key associated with my username/password.

Comment: I can argue that simply relying on appid may not be a great/secure idea but there is another bigger problem here with this: one FIDO U2F device should be able to be associated with different facebook accounts so it wouldn't work to use appid only.

Comment: I'm curious why you think appid would not be secure. The login to different accounts is controlled by the username. The logic at the server is the same (1. check password, 2. verify signature) but it can be achieved with fewer protocol exchanges.

Comment: Let's forget the security (still present anyway) argument for now.
U2F device -that do NOT store any username- can have several keys associated to a same appid so you can't use appid only, so you need Key Handle (key id/references) and so you need to identify users, then to find associated Key Handle(s), then to send it/them to the U2F client and U2F device to do the real authentication.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right Frederic! Thanks for your patience explaining this to me. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the server must know who is going to login, is this case, username must be provided. Which the first process you provided is an identification process that the server needs to retrieve who gonna login in the whole database. While the second one is the authentication process which the server needs to authenticate the user is the right person. Normally, when you login to a certain website, it is an authentication process, that's why we need one more step.

Comment: We're doing two-factor authentication, but it doesn't need to be two protocol steps, the two factors (password, signed challenge) can be passed in a single step, no? Then the server checks the password and verifies the signature based on the encrypted password and public key associated with the login name... all in a single protocol step.

Comment: Regarding to the specification [https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.1-id-20160915/fido-u2f-javascript-api-v1.1-id-20160915.html#high-level-javascript-api](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.1-id-20160915/fido-u2f-javascript-api-v1.1-id-20160915.html#high-level-javascript-api) The sever needs to pass "registeredKeys" to the client, which should be binding with a certain INDEX Key in your database, like an username for example. Otherwise the server does who is going to request that makes no sense for an authentication. I think it does relate to security but business logic.